# How to enable code completion / code sense for Sencha on Textmate

Tags: extjs, codesense

I been using CODA for long time and now planning a move to TextMate.

In the sencha screen cast i see the presenters getting a lot of code completion. How do i enable the same.

Answer (score 1):

Code completion is possible through the use of Haxe JS and a textmate bundle.

http://haxe.org/com/ide/textmate

http://www.haxejs.org/externs/sencha-touch/

You should be set following the instructions on those 2 links.